# Php file can not connect to local sock

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, macos

I am relatively new to php and mysql and I am having a problem with my mysql. It is an error I am getting and I have tried everything I know of.So from the error I can only assume it is a socket problem. Here is the Error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysqld.sock' (2) in /homepages/35/d372939724/htdocs/mypetdetective.org/posting.php on line 26
```

Could not Connect

And here is the php file:

```
<?php

$posting_title = $_POST['post_title'];
$post_des = $_POST['post_des'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', '__MUNGED__', '__MUNGED__' ,'__MUNGED__')
or die( 'Could not Connect' );

$query = "INSERT INTO lost_cat(title,description)".
"VALUES('$posting_title','$post_des')";

mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
or die('error in query');

mysqli_close($dbc);

echo '<b class="lom">' . $posting_title . '</b>' .'<br />';
echo '<hr />';
echo $post_des . '<br />';

?>
```

Comment: Yes I have made sure a few times that it is.

Comment: Did you really just post your MySQL root password in a public forum?

Comment: Are you running mysql using a local installation, or xampp?

Comment: Tip: instead of `die('error in query')` which tells you absolutely nothing useful, try `die(mysql_error())` so you get the exact reason the query barfed.

Answer (score 0):

Find your my.cnf file, for me, the file is located here /Applications/XAMPP/etc/my.cnf. Please note, due to your custom installation, the configuration file is highly likely to be elsewhere, I was simply posting my location as an example :)

There should be a [client] section, and in there you should see a socket directive. Make sure that is set to /tmp/mysqld.sock. If that doesn't work, please also set it in the [mysqld] section. Restart your mysql server, and it should be up and running!

Below, is exactly what the line should look like

```
socket      = /tmp/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the mysql server running?  It doesn't appear to be from the look of that error. You state that your mac is showing you it is running, but it looks from the information provided that it's not reachable by clients.  Try [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-m)

One other thing you should try to debug this is to try and connect using the mysql command line client:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: Yeah I just checked it is running.

Comment: I have snow lepeord so I just checked in system preferences